# Leverage current SSMS environment and create a "LOCAL DATABASE"

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssms

I currently have my tables all connected to a server on my company's network with views built off of those tables.

I want to recreate this environment on my client's local desktop. I currently upload my excel tables to the server so I would like to connect this local environment directly to the excel files.

Is there a feature of SSMS that would allow me to do this, or any alternative DBM services that would allow for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Two clarifying questions: (1) Are you trying to give your client access to the server on your company's network so you can directly work with your excel files? (2) Are you trying to recreate your company's database on your client's machine?

Comment: I am trying to recreate my database on my client's machine. My envisioned configuration entails creating a folder on the desktop that is the "server" or the "database", and a series of CSV or XLSX files that are the tables. This would allow me to reuse the queries I have already built as long as all table names and column names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the SQL Server Import/Export wizard. It allows you to create a database complete with tables directly from an Excel file. You can find more details here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/